# key not being recognized by api.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: bug, status-completed, rate-limit

I have been testing a throttle implementation against meta today and suddenly got shut down with a key violation.

It is *possible* that I have used enough requests to prompt this but I doubt it.

In any case, is this a proper response for an 'out of requests' error?

Should it not include the 'x-rate-limit' headers?

Or is this a sign of another problem?

```
GET /1.0/tags?page=288&pagesize=100&jsonp=Soapi._jsonp151&key=insert-key-here  HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:17742/tests-throttle.htm
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: api.meta.stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 20 Aug 2010 17:10:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 127

Soapi._jsonp151({
  "error": {
    "code": 4004,
    "message": "This IP has exceeded the request-per-day limit."
  }
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The omission of the `X-...` headers was a bug, and has been resolved.

Be aware, if you provide a key that actually isn't recognized you'll get a 4000 error back not a 4004.